# How do I capture csrf / xsrf token/cookie in Postman with Interceptor from Spring Boot with Spring Security?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, postman, csrf, q

`
First of all I am sorry about the format of this question. I tried to format the code but I only got error messages.

I have been trying for quite some time now, searching StackOverflow and all over the webb. I am following a Tutorial on Spring Security etc...and specifically Basic Authentication where I am supposed to capture csrf-token in Postman with Enterceptor. I have searched many threads here on StackOverflow and tried many things but I have not been able to solve it yet.

I have been reading about problems with security and SameSite= Lax and so on but I am not very confident in what to do and do where...

Since the "websecurityconfigureradapter" is deprecated, I tried to write my own SecurityConfig-file...

maybe there is something wrong with that?

I would very much appreciate any help.`

have been trying the following in my config-file:

http.csrf(csrf -> csr
.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()));

---

with the following script in Postman test tab in the request:

var xsrfCookie = postman.getResponseCookie("XSRF-TOKEN");
pm.environment.set("xsrf-token", decodeURIComponent(pm.cookies.get("XSRF-TOKEN")));

with Header:  X-XSRF {{xsrf-token}}

I have tried to install some kind of SSL-certificate in Postman, but I am not quite sure
how that works.
I have also read about how to set Flags in Google Chrome to control SameSite in some way but I have a version of Chrome (109) where I can´t set flags anymore.

And I have read somewhere that there is some problem with SameSite...and localhost?

Comment: If you are using Spring Security 6, see [exploits](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/exploits.html#_protect_against_csrf_breach) in the [5.8 migration guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/index.html) to learn how to prepare for changes in 6.0. Having said that, I don't think I understand your question. Please provide more information. I also recommend some research on CSRF, there are many great general and specific articles on this topic and other answers on SO.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes thank you so much for the help. I am sorry about missing code. I could not make the <tags> work. I Will check the 5.8 - 6.0 security topic. Thank you!